# How to delay the shake notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I want to delay the shake for 5 seconds because if the user continuously shakes the device, the response is showing null. So that is why I want to delay the shake until n unless response is alive.

Here's my code is

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {

        [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"User shaked to update"];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CheckWeather" object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"startWeatherNeue" object:nil];

        if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] )

            [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in objective c i use **sleep(6)** for stop processing,
put sleep(6) befor your fired notification code:-

```
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {

 sleep(6);

[FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"User shaked to update"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CheckWeather" object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"startWeatherNeue" object:nil];

if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] )

    [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];

    } 
 }
```

and then process stop for 6 second and then  notification fire after 6 seconde may be its helpful for you

**other**

u also use NSTimer :-

in NSTimer u check your response array count >0 in if else condition and call method with 1 second when your response array > 0 then call NSNOtification method

here my example :- with NSTimer

```
  -(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
 {

  self.TimeOfActiveUser = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:01.0  target:self   selector:@selector(checkInfoString) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }


 -(IBAction)checkInfoString
 {

    if([responsearray count]>0)
    {
    [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"User shaked to update"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CheckWeather" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"startWeatherNeue" object:nil];

        if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] )
        {
          [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];
         } 

    }
   else
    {

     NSLOG
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you nitin, i will try to check this code in my requirement and see how it works !!

Answer (score 1):

To perform some selector later you can use:

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```